# How to use value from RETURNING id as parameter in other function - Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

When clicking on a button I want two things to happen:

1. Insert form-data into table_1 with the insert_function.
2. Use the id of the newly inserted row in table_1 as parameter to a function: other_func_name(id).

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
var jsnPolygon = returnFormData("class_name");
jsnPolygon.tbl = "table_1";
var id = insert_function(jsnPolygon);
other_func_name(id);
});
```

The insert_function looks like this:

```
function insert_function(jsnPolygon, callback) {
    delete jsnPolygon.id; // makes sure to give it a fresh id
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/insert_record.php',
        data: jsnPolygon,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.substr(0, 5) == "ERROR") {
                alert(response);
            } else {
                switch (jsnPolygon.tbl) {
                    case "table_1":
                        break;    
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("AJAX Error: " + error);
        }
    });
};
```

And the insert_record query looks like this:

```
$sqlQuery="INSERT INTO {$table} ({$keys}created, createdby, modified, modifiedby) 
           VALUES ({$vals}current_date, '{$username}', current_date, '{$username}') 
           RETURNING id";
            $result = $pdo->prepare($sqlQuery);
            $result->execute($_POST);
            echo $sqlQuery;
```

Inserting the data works fine, but how do I get other_func_name(id) to understand the value of id?

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two long days and multiple mental breakdowns, I have finally managed to solve the problem. It turned out to be several challenges in the question.

First of, getting the id from the insert_record was solved with `fetchColumn`, like this:

```
$sqlQuery="INSERT INTO {$table} ({$keys}created, createdby, modified, modifiedby) 
VALUES ({$vals}current_date, '{$username}', current_date, '{$username}') 
RETURNING id as id";
            $result = $pdo->prepare($sqlQuery);
            $result->execute($_POST);
            $id = $result->fetchColumn();
echo $id;
```

Then a new problem arise with how the `insert_function(jsnPolygon)` was built. It returned nothing due to its asynchronous nature. I solved it by using Promise and rewrote it like this:

```
function insert_function(jsnPolygon, callback) {
    delete jsnPolygon.id; // makes sure to get a fresh id
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/insert_record.php',
        data: jsnPolygon,
        type: 'POST',
        success: resolve,
        error: reject
    }); 
    });
}
```

Then finally the tricky part of the click-event was changed to this:

```
insert_function(jsnPolygon).then(result =>{
                var id = result;
                other_func_name(id);
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                alert("ERROR")
            });
```

Hope that helped someone!

Answer (score 0):

The `insert ... returning` query returns a rowset just like `select`. You can get the returned values by calling [`query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead of [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php).

Comment: I'm horrible new to this, so I need a few more clues. Changing "execute" to "query" didn't help. Shouldn't there be a "return id;" or something in the insert_function?

Comment: Yeah, the call to query() will return a rowset. The ID will be in the first column of the first row.